# styling i18n messages in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, internationalization

I have chrome extension with settings/help page.
There is no problem with settings because it's mostly short text snippets enable this, enable that...
But, help page is problematic.
It is much bigger text blocks and they are formated with `<li>` tags in which I have styled some parts of the text with `<b>` or `...color="red"`
example:

```
<li>some text with <b>bold text</b> and then the rest of it... </li>
```

To use internationalization on help page, do I need to break that line into three different messages, like this

```
<li><span data-i18n="key_1"></span><b data-i18n="key_2"></b><span  data-i18n="key_3"></span></li>


{
    "key_1": {
        "message": "some text with"
    },
    "key_2": {
        "message": " bold text"
    },
    "key_3": {
        "message": " and then the rest of it... "
    }
}
```

or there is some more intelligent way in this situation?

ps. I'm fetching all data-i18n and replacing tags textContent with according message under data-i18n attribute value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm fetching all data-i18n and replacing tags textContent with according message under data-i18n attribute value.

Well, you could always store HTML snippets in messages and replace innerHTML instead.